# Magento StoreCode language tag redirect

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I'm trying to redirect the pretty made language tag `ch-de` to the Magento store view store code `ch_de`.

But instead it remove the first param and replace it with second, it just add it at the end. so it always look like mydomain.com/ch-de/ch_en/ even in the switcher which really confuse me.

Here is the part from .htaccess:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

#RewriteBase /magento/

#############################################
##  redirect all non-www urls to www
##  mod by pagewerkstatt

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#############################################
##  add for "base urls" the trailing Slash
##

RewriteRule ^([^.]+[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]


############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

SetEnvIf Request_URI "index.php/api/(v2_)?soap/" is_backend=0

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_REWRITE_IS_FINISHED} !1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/api/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/js/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/skin/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/media/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/adminguru.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ch-de/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^ch-de/?(.*) $1 [E=URL_LOCALE:ch-de,E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:ch_de]
RewriteRule ^ch-fr/?(.*) $1 [E=URL_LOCALE:ch-fr,E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:ch_fr]
RewriteRule ^ch-en/?(.*) $1 [E=URL_LOCALE:ch-en,E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:ch_en]
RewriteRule ^de-de/?(.*) $1 [E=URL_LOCALE:de-de,E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:de_de]
RewriteRule ^de-en/?(.*) $1 [E=URL_LOCALE:de-en,E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:de_en]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

SetEnv REWRITE_IS_FINISHED 1
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

You can see it here: http://www.sponser.ch/

I would be very thankful for any advice.

Comment: Have you tried `RewriteBase /`?